# Azure - setting tags on VMs using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, tags, virtual-machine

I'm using the following Powershell code to set tags on a bunch of Azure VMs but it doesn't seem to be working. It does not give me an error message, so it appears to run correctly, but it does not set the tags as expected. Any help would be great, perhaps it may be something easy I'm overlooking.

```
$group = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name my-rg
$resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceName myserver -ResourceGroupName my-rg
Set-AzResource -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -Tag $group.Tags -Force
```

I'm only doing a few VMs which I'll probably put on a loop once this works. There are no tags on most of these VMs which may be overwritten.

Comment: The code as is work without issues on my end. Maybe if you add more context. Try adding verbose output to see if `$group.Tags` values are good before applying them.

Comment: That's whats really puzzling, it runs properly on my side too but for some reason it's not updating the tags. Setting the verbose flag gives me:                   VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Updating the resource..." on target "/subscriptions/....." and a table below that says the operation succeeded as shown below:     VMName               Location ProvisioningState VMSize          OS SKU OSVersion AdminUserName NetworkInterfaceName
svr name eastus   Succeeded         Standard_D2s_v3                                svr-name.

Comment: Add -Debug to the Set-AzResource operation.  Do you see the tags in the outgoing body for the PATCH operation?  What is the response from Azure?  If you immediately do another Get-AzResource (also adding the -Debug parameter), what do you see?  Are the tags in the response body?

Comment: `$group.tags` probably empty

Comment: Doesn't the command return all the VM properties with the new tags? The command always return it.

Comment: Just checking in to inform that this is working now. Don't know how but the exact same code as yesterday shows the expected results. The tags from the RG are copied to the Resource. Thanks everyone for chiming in.

Comment: Well, you can add an answer to explain something. Or just delete the question.